# Include different XSLT in browser-side XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML which I am trying to display using XSLT as a report.
I have included the following line in the XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="report.xslt"?>
```

But I have some styling elements which I call from `report.xslt` in a different XSLT (`reportStyle.xslt`). I call these using the `<call-template>` in the `report.xslt`.

My question is:
How can I include the third XSLT (`reportStyle.xslt`)?
At the moment the XML is getting transformed, but it is not styled how I want it to be in the `reportStyle.xslt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost answered your question yourself.
Use [`<xsl:include href="URI"/>`](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/ref_xsl_el_include.asp) to include `reportStyle.xslt` in `report.xslt`.

So you have your XML with

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="report.xslt"?>
```

and `report.xslt` with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0>
  <xsl:include href="reportStyle.xslt"/>
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The all your `<call-template>`s can call `report.xslt` templates as well as `reportStyle.xslt` templates.